# Jar does not run despite specifying correct main class, classpath, etc

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

My build compiles and runs perfectly using the `build.xml` file below.

The only problem is I create a jar but it does not run without giving the `Could not find or load main class` error.

I have read several Stack Overflow answers on the common `Could not find or load main class` error.  I cannot spot what I am doing wrong in my `build.xml` below, however.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="run" name="My Project ">

<target name="run" depends="createjar">
    <java classname="com.company.program.project.MyMainClass">
        <classpath path="staging">
            <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
              <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="createjar" depends="compile">
  <jar destfile="./builds/jars/swtgui.jar" basedir="./staging/com/company/program/project" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.company.program.project.MyMainClass" />
    </manifest>

    <!-- 
        <fileset dir="./bin/com/company/program/project" includes="./*.class" />
    -->
    <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\" includes="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b.jar" />
  </jar>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
        <classpath>
             <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
              <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

</target>

<record name="./MyMainClass.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

**MyProject.log**

```
createjar:
  [jar] found a total of 0 manifests in 2 resource collections
  [jar] A$1.class added as A$1.class is outdated.
  [jar] A$10.class added as A$10.class is outdated.
  [jar] A$11.class added as A$11.class is outdated.
  [jar] ...
  [jar] No sources found.
        [jar] Building jar: C:\my_workspace\my_project\builds\jars\swtgui.jar
  [jar] adding directory META-INF/
  [jar] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  [jar] adding entry A$1.class
  [jar] adding entry A$10.class
  [jar] adding entry A$11.class
  [jar] adding entry org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b.jar
  [jar] No Implementation-Title set.No Implementation-Version set.No Implementation-Vendor set.
Location: C:\my_workspace\my_project\build.xml:16: 
createjar:  duration 0 seconds
```

The main class is correctly specified.  The classpath (basedir) is correctly specified. It waits before compile is finished to execute.  Etc.

I left my log file below, but it doesn't seem like `ant` gives any clues on why it can't find my main class.  Does anyone spot anything immediately wrong with the above two files?

Comment: I believe your jar file has structuer like src/com/xxx ....the internal structure should be com/asd/...  ..try changing basedir="./staging/com/company/program/project" to basedir="./staging/com/company/program/project/<your folder where class files are generated>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `basedir` property of the `jar` task should match the `destdir` property of the `javac` task.

The `javac` task is written as

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
```

Therefore the `jar` task should be written as

```
<jar destfile="./builds/jars/swtgui.jar" basedir="staging" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
```

Since your package is defined as `com.company.program.project`, the Java Compiler as well as the JVM expect your classes in a folder `com/company/program/project`, but your current `jar` task puts them into the root folder of the jar file.

Comment: Very good.  That got it past the `Could not find or load main class error.`  It can't see the lone library (SWT), though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try eclipse--> export-->Runnable jar file option?

I also faced this problem when i try to create a jar from my test swing app manually. But when I tried this option it worked.